# encrypted connection via unixODBC to postgresql?

Tags: database, odbc, unixodbc

We are connecting to postgresql via unixODBC (our operating system is Centos 6.x). Is the connection encrypted? Or how to set the connection encrypted (include transfering password)?
I have searched google but there was not a clear answer.
Many thanks !

Answer (score 0):

The use of encrypted connections depends on the ODBC Driver, not the ODBC Driver Manager (unixODBC).

I think you can set the ODBC Driver for PostgreSQL (psqlODBC) to use SSL by setting:

```
sslmode = require
```

either in the Connection String or in the odbc.ini file.